# AM and PM help in java

Tags: java

I am having trouble with this program. I enter a AM time and a PM time. However when I get to 12 O'Clock everything gets messed up. It keeps adding 13,14,15, etc. Is there a way I can get set 13=1 , 14=2 , 15=3, etc.?

```
String format = "HH:mm:ss a";
SimpleDateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);
System.out.println("enter what time first person is leaving");
int leaving1 = in.nextInt();
System.out.println("enter if 1(am) 2(pm)");
int ampm = in.nextInt();
```

---

```
if (ampm == 1 && ampm2 == 2){

while (leaving1 <= 12){

sametime++;
}
leaving1 = leaving1+sametime-12;
System.out.println(leaving1);
```

Comment: It sounds like it's just using the 24 hour notation, which does away with AM and PM.  You'd have to provide us a sample of your code so that we could get a better picture, although I feel that PSR's answer may go a ways to helping you out.

Comment: even if it storing it in 24 hour clock format not to worry you can convert this to 12 hour clock by using SimpleDateFormat.
but make sure SimpleDateFormat should be initialized locally in method because it's not thread safe.

Comment: I added some sample code @Makoto

Comment: why wont leaving1 print out? (in the second code segment)

Answer (score 0):

Your time format is incorrect.

Per the documentation for [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), `HH:mm:ss a` will always produce a time format in 24-hour notation, since `H` is geared to output 24-hour time values.

The fix is simple:  Change it to a lowercase h.  Use two if you want a leading zero for hours between 1 and 10.

```
String format = "h:mm:ss a";
```

or:

```
String format = "hh:mm:ss a";
```

Comment: why wont leaving1 print out? (in the second code segment)

Comment: That's not the question I set out to answer...seems like you kind of snuck that in.  But, you've got an infinite loop there.  You'd do best to figure out why you're not updating `leaving1` if you're going to use that in your loop.

Comment: leaving1 is a number I input